# Show all related list on detail page except one using Visualforce page and standard controller

Tags: visualforce, related-list

I have created one vf page to show details of Account record. On page, Except "Opportunities" related list I want to show all other related lists.
I was trying with code as shown below but it is not working-

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardController="Account">
    <apex:detail>
        <apex:relatedList list="Opportunities" rendered="false" />
    </apex:detail>
</apex:page>
```

Any help/suggestion is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Its an all or nothing for related list in detail. So the best way to do this is set related list to false in detail and manually display the related list as you need.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
   <apex:detail subject="{!account.ownerId}" relatedList="false" title="false"/> 
   <apex:relatedList list="Contacts">
      <apex:facet name="header">Titles can be overriden with facets</apex:facet> 
   </apex:relatedList>
   <apex:relatedList list="Cases" title="Or you can keep the image, but change the text" />
</apex:page>
```